# How to write string data to a stream in chunks, not a lump

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, ipc

I have a node.js script, which must accept utf8 data on STDIN and output other utf8 data on STDOUT
It's intended to accept a TAP string(s) from the tape testing framework runner through a shell pipe and slightly modify it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

process.stdin.setDefaultEncoding('utf8');
process.stdout.setDefaultEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  let chunk;
  while ((chunk = process.stdin.read()) !== null) {
    process.stdout.write('chunk: ' + chunk);
  }
});

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
  process.stdout.write('end\n');
});
```

When I run it with a tape test `npm run test-unit test/unit/main.test.js | ./format.js` I get (further I'll refer to it as the "**live output**"):

```
chunk: 
> dummy@0.0.0 test-unit /path/dummy/zzz
> tape "test/unit/main.test.js"

chunk: TAP version 13
chunk: # test 1
chunk: # comment 1
chunk: ok 1 should be equal
chunk: 
1..1
chunk: # tests 1
# pass  1

# ok
chunk: 
end
```

So you can see, the data, sort of, were written 8 times, in 8 chunks.

**My question is, how can I simulate this behavior in a test?**

In the test I spawned another process with `spawn('./format.js')` but how can I write to that process' STDIN so that it'd take 8 times to read the same data, as from the tap reporter.

I split the original tap output (without the "chunk" marks) into an array of strings (equivalent to the chunks from the *live output*) and tried to write each string in a separate write call to the spawned.stdin then test the `format.js`'s output:

```
let spawned = spawn('./format.js');
let chunksOriginal = [
  // chunks here
];


spawned.stdout.on('readable', () => {
  console.log(spawned.stdout.read());
});
chunksOriginal.forEach((chunk, i) => {
  spawned.stdin.write(chunk);
});
```

I expected `console.log` to spew the same string as the *live output*, or at least to be only the first chunk from it but I got:

```
chunk: 
> dummy@0.0.0 test-unit /path/dummy/zzz
> tape "test/unit/main.test.js"

TAP version 13
# test 1
# comment 1
ok 1 should be equal

1..1
# tests 1
# pass  1

# ok

end
```

As you can see the data were read by the `format.js` just once, with one chunk mark above. I tried to emit the "readable" event in the forEach loop before the write call, that didn't help either:

```
chunksOriginal.forEach((chunk, i) => {
  spawned.stdin.emit('readable');
  spawned.stdin.write(chunk);
});
```

*I suspect that the problem is that I don't understand conceptually IPC in node.js and bash. Data in the "live output", probably, is written via a so-called node.js Buffer.*

*I'm not asking for an exact solution to the problem, though I'd be greatly thankful if someone provided it.*

*Just a hint on a conceptual level, where should I look, in what docs, to solve this would be appreaciated*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also I tried to use `setTimeout`, to make the write process asynchronous, though I forgot to mention this in the question, but it didn't help then either:

```
chunksOriginal.forEach((chunk, i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    spawned.stdin.emit('readable');
    spawned.stdin.write(chunk);
  }, i);
});
```

---

Then I gave it one more try and increased the delay `i * 100` ms namely, and it worked:

```
chunksOriginal.forEach((chunk, i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    spawned.stdin.write(chunk);
  }, i * 100);
});
```

That helped, now the `format.js` receives the same amount of chunks from the dummy input, as it receives from the live one (though it all may need some tuning, config creation).

*Also it's worth to note that the emit call is unnecessary*.